# Create subplots dynamically in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to create subplots dynamically in matlab ?

I have a variable **X** that determines the number of graphs to be plotted, i was wondering if there was a way to dynamically create these graphs since **X** will vary according to a certain scenario

I currently allocate the number of subplots beforehand like so:

```
figure

ax1 = subplot(3,1,1); 
ax2 = subplot(3,1,2); 
ax3 = subplot(3,1,3); 

plot(ax1,ins,state_vec(:,1),'b',x,100,'r','LineWidth',2)
plot(ax2,ins,state_vec(:,2),'b',x,100,'r','LineWidth',2)
plot(ax3,ins,state_vec(:,3),'b',x,100,'r','LineWidth',2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want them in one column (just like you have them now), a simple for loop should do it:

```
figure

for i = 1:X
    axi = subplot(X,1,i)
    plot(axi,ins,state_vec(:,i),'b',x,100,'r','LineWidth',2)
end
```

If you want a grid, you'll have to be cleverer than that, but you can do it with two for loops. If you can, try R + ggplot2! :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still asking this question, MATLAB since R2019b now recommends using the [tiledlayout](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html?lang=en) and [nexttile](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/nexttile.html) function pair to dynamically arrange multiple plots inside one figure, e.g.

```
tiledlayout('flow')
nexttile
plot(x,y1)
nexttile
plot(x,y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be a square, you can do:

```
figure

sqSize = ceil(sqrt(X));
for i=1:X
    subplot(sqSize,sqSize,i);
    <plot stuff>
end
```